# Is there anyway you can invert the fill of a single polygon on QGIS when you have several polygons in the layer?

Tags: qgis

I have used QGIS inverted polygon fill too but was wondering if you could isolate individual polygons - a bit like the atlas feature?

Comment: Sure, just use rule based styling.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make it match up with the atlas feature so that when I cycle through that the inverted polygon fills reflect that too? Kinda new to styling options etc. within QGIS

Comment: Yes, use the atlas-related variables (eg @atlas_feature, @atlas_pagename) in the expression builder.